# Windows to DirectX mouse coordinates

Tags: windows, directx

I'making a game using Windows and DirectX. I've set the window and the device 1024x768 both of them

```
Windows:

RECT r={0,0,1024,768};
int style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU;
AdjustWindowRect(&r,style,false);

CreateWindow...

DirectX:

d3dpp.BackBufferWidth=1024;
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight=768;

CreateDevice...
```

However, when I read the mouse position using

```
GetCursorPos(&p);
ScreenToClient(g_hWnd, &p);
```

some returned coordinates are outside the 1024x768 borders. I have to say that if I render a sprite using (0,0,1024,768) coordinate limits, DirectX will display it as if it were working with 1024x768.

How can I convert from the 1024x768 of DirectX to the 1024x768 of Windows?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...or from Windows to DirectX. I'd need at least the appropiate formula to make the conversion, if not configuring DirectX device with the appropiate values

Answer (score 1):

That was it. Thanks very much for this piece of code, it works great. Much more nicer solution than mine. Anyway, my tests showed me that printing values of p from

```
GetCursorPos(&p);
ScreenToClient(g_hWnd, &p);
```

for some mappings the coordinates were even outside the borders of the window. Because of this I didn't think to consider only the borders and title of the window. Is it maybe something related to

```
AdjustWindowRect(&r,style,false); ?
```

Last question. Do you know if the offset (+6,+28) is always going to be the same for title and borders? If not, do you know of a generic way to ask for these values?

Again, thanks very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear about your problem. But if your problem is switching from directX into window, is because window have its space for title and border. So set the window to 800x600 (if your video size is 800x600) will not work here!

```
    windowHwnd = CreateWindow(windowClass.lpszClassName, L"love", MY_WINDOW_STYLE , preWindowPosX,preWindowPosY,    
                Video.Width+6, Video.Height+28, GetDesktopWindow(), NULL, windowClass.hInstance, NULL);
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth=Video.Width;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight=Video.Height;
```

Instead you, have +6,and +28. into the window size, everything will be OK!
My App is working fine in windowed mode and full Screen mode, support many resolutions!